# Multiple criteria for index match

Tags: indexing, match, vlookup

=INDEX([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$F:$F,MATCH(S2&B2,[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$E:$E,0))
Used this formula to pick 2 criteria i.e, data code and record type to arrive at GL account. But the result is #NA error. Also, used concatenate formula and merged the criteria and did vlook up but the error #NA still remains. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zze2x.png)Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. I will assume that the table you pasted a picture of is the table you want to RETRIEVE "GL Account" from. I'm not sure why this table would already have an #N/A in it, but know that if you have an #N/A in your lookup table, it's possible for a correctly working formula to return an #N/A, because that's the value it found.

[image: Index/Match Example]

I used tables/columns with intuitive names to make it easier to follow the formula:

```
=INDEX(LookupTable[GL Account],MATCH([@[Value to use in lookup]],LookupTable[Lookup Value],0))
```

I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with the formula you posted, but it's just not clear what you are doing with it, what data is in which cells, etc. But hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to retrieve GL account from the data. the error is after giving the formula and below rows are pasted in the table without formula. I will check and get back thanks a lot :)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to lookup GL account from within the same table you are storing GL account in. You should have two separate tables. Can you share them both?